# Oracle Trigger Still carrying old value for New

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I write some trigger to automatically change value in state_id field in ESTABLISHMENT table after user updating ADDRESS table through online apps. The Issue is, when user updating OTHER_STATE_ID = 16 and POSTAL_STATE_ID = 16 in tble Address, the value for OTHER_STATE_ID in table ESTABLISHMENT still carrying old value. Only POSTAL_STATE_ID field updated with new value. I have check the trigger code and found out nothing weird code. It seems that the trigger keep old value for updating other_state_id. Here are data scenario:-

1. Before updating (ADDRESS table)

   - For ADDRESS_TYPE = 1, value LOCATION_STATE_ID = **8**
   - For ADDRESS_TYPE = 2, value POSTAL_STATE_ID = **8**
   - For ADDRESS_TYPE = 11, value OTHER_STATE_ID = **8**

   Before triggering (ESTABLISHMENT table)

   - value LOCATION_STATE_ID = **8**
   - value POSTAL_STATE_ID = **8**
   - value OTHER_STATE_ID = **8**
2. Value after updating (ADDRESS table)

   - User update value LOCATION_STATE_ID = **8**
   - For ADDRESS_TYPE = 2, value POSTAL_STATE_ID = **16**
   - For ADDRESS_TYPE = 11, value OTHER_STATE_ID = **16**

   After triggering (ESTABLISHMENT table)

   - value LOCATION_STATE_ID = **8**
   - value POSTAL_STATE_ID = **16**
   - value OTHER_STATE_ID = **8**

Maybe something weird happen in this lines of codes. Anyone..?

Full Codes As below

> ```
>     create or replace
> TRIGGER "TR_ADDRESS_EE"
>    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
>    ON ADDRESS
>    FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
>    IF INSERTING
>    THEN
>       IF (:NEW.STATE_ID IS NOT NULL)
>       THEN
>          IF (:NEW.RECORD_TYPE_ID = 401)
>          THEN
>             IF (:NEW.ADDRESS_TYPE = 1)
>             THEN
>                UPDATE ESTABLISHMENT
>                   SET LOCATION_STATE_ID = :NEW.STATE_ID
>                 WHERE ESTABLISHMENT_ID = :NEW.RECORD_ID;
>             ELSIF (:NEW.ADDRESS_TYPE = 2)
>             THEN
>                UPDATE ESTABLISHMENT
>                   SET POSTAL_STATE_ID = :NEW.STATE_ID
>                 WHERE ESTABLISHMENT_ID = :NEW.RECORD_ID;
>             ELSIF (:NEW.ADDRESS_TYPE = 11)
>             THEN
>                UPDATE ESTABLISHMENT
>                   SET OTHER_STATE_ID = :NEW.STATE_ID
>                 WHERE ESTABLISHMENT_ID = :NEW.RECORD_ID;
>             END IF;
>          END IF;
>       END IF;
>    ELSIF UPDATING ('STATE_ID')
>    THEN
>       IF (:OLD.RECORD_TYPE_ID = 401 AND :NEW.STATE_ID <> :OLD.STATE_ID)
>       THEN
>          IF (:NEW.ADDRESS_TYPE = 1)
>          THEN
>             UPDATE ESTABLISHMENT
>                SET LOCATION_STATE_ID = :NEW.STATE_ID
>              WHERE ESTABLISHMENT_ID = :OLD.RECORD_ID;
>          ELSIF (:NEW.ADDRESS_TYPE = 2)
>          THEN
>             UPDATE ESTABLISHMENT
>                SET POSTAL_STATE_ID = :NEW.STATE_ID
>              WHERE ESTABLISHMENT_ID = :OLD.RECORD_ID;
>          ELSIF (:NEW.ADDRESS_TYPE = 11)
>          THEN
>             UPDATE ESTABLISHMENT
>                SET OTHER_STATE_ID = :NEW.STATE_ID
>              WHERE ESTABLISHMENT_ID = :OLD.RECORD_ID;
>          END IF;
>       END IF;
>    END IF;
> END;
> ```

Comment: [Seems OK to me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/79c71/1). Maybe you need to show (by editing the question, not as comments) your table creation statements and all your insert and update statements to see what's different, since I had to make those up. I wouldn't recommend  trying to maintain duplicate data via triggers though; why not make `establishment` a view over `address`?

Comment: The purpose of maintain duplicate data via triggers because address table is used by different module. so ESTABLISHMENT should have latest state_id updated from various source,

Comment: Are you sure you don't have other triggers updating the ESTABLISHMENT table?

Comment: yup sure. I dropped and recreate the triggers. For sometime it shows correct result. But after a while, error return. so do i need to repair the trigger again?